# R: Compare two data.frames and delete data that not match

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have two data.frame time series. The first is complete, the second is containing only the time steps with correct values of one of the variables. I need to keep all other variables but want to NA all the variables which appear in the second df. Here the example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

#test data:
TDF <- tibble(DATE = seq( make_datetime(2007,09,23,06,00), make_datetime(2008,07,05,23,00), by = 600),
          V1 = round(runif(length(DATE)),2),
          V2 = round(runif(length(DATE)),2),
          V3 = round(runif(length(DATE)),2))
TDF2 <- TDF
TDF2 <- TDF2[TDF2$V1>0.7,]
```

Output:

```
> TDF
# A tibble: 41,287 × 4
                  DATE    V1    V2    V3
                <dttm> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  2007-09-23 06:00:00  0.89  0.21  0.03
2  2007-09-23 06:10:00  0.26  0.54  0.70
3  2007-09-23 06:20:00  0.74  0.22  0.80
4  2007-09-23 06:30:00  0.31  0.48  0.38
5  2007-09-23 06:40:00  0.93  0.26  0.21

> TDF2
# A tibble: 11,972 × 4
                  DATE    V1    V2    V3
                <dttm> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  2007-09-23 06:00:00  0.89  0.21  0.03
2  2007-09-23 06:20:00  0.74  0.22  0.80
3  2007-09-23 06:40:00  0.93  0.26  0.21
4  2007-09-23 07:20:00  0.91  0.36  0.83
5  2007-09-23 07:40:00  0.95  0.87  0.91
```

And this is what I need:

```
> TDF_modified
# A tibble: 41,287 × 4
                  DATE    V1    V2    V3
                <dttm> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  2007-09-23 06:00:00  0.89  0.21  0.03
2  2007-09-23 06:10:00  NA    0.54  0.70
3  2007-09-23 06:20:00  0.74  0.22  0.80
4  2007-09-23 06:30:00  NA    0.48  0.38
5  2007-09-23 06:40:00  0.93  0.26  0.21
```

I need a general solution just by using the two data.frames. I could do it via loop but I bet there is a more elegant way. Thanks a lot in advanced!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not entirely clear to me what you are looking for, but based on your example output, it appears that you want to keep the results for `V2` and `V3` from TDF, and only remove the `V1` reading.

One approach would be to use `left_join` without the `V1` column from `TDF` and with only the `V1` column from `TDF2`:

```
left_join(
  select(TDF, -V1)
  , select(TDF2, DATE, V1) )
```

Gives:

```
                  DATE    V2    V3    V1
                <dttm> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  2007-09-23 06:00:00  0.14  0.62    NA
2  2007-09-23 06:10:00  0.87  0.05  0.87
3  2007-09-23 06:20:00  0.20  0.52    NA
4  2007-09-23 06:30:00  0.34  0.01    NA
5  2007-09-23 06:40:00  0.92  0.37  0.83
6  2007-09-23 06:50:00  0.94  0.27    NA
7  2007-09-23 07:00:00  0.98  0.49    NA
8  2007-09-23 07:10:00  0.70  0.98    NA
9  2007-09-23 07:20:00  0.05  0.55  0.72
10 2007-09-23 07:30:00  0.16  0.12  0.99
```

from my randomized data.

If you are looking for a more complete solution, you could do a `full_join`, which will yield duplicated columns, and then handle them as you wish to. E.g., this returns `NA` for `V1` if `TDF2$V1` is missing, but for `V2` and `V3` it gives the `TDF` value if missing, and only gives `NA` if the two values are present and different. Since I am not sure what you want to use, you may need to add more complicated checks here.

```
full_join(TDF, TDF2, "DATE") %>%
  mutate(V1 = ifelse(is.na(V1.y), NA, V1.x)
         , V2 = ifelse(is.na(V2.y), V2.x
                       , ifelse(V2.x == V2.y, V2.x, NA))
         , V3 = ifelse(is.na(V3.y), V3.x
                       , ifelse(V3.x == V3.y, V3.x, NA))
         )
```

Returns:

```
# A tibble: 41,287 × 10
                  DATE  V1.x  V2.x  V3.x  V1.y  V2.y  V3.y    V1    V2    V3
                <dttm> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  2007-09-23 06:00:00  0.62  0.14  0.62    NA    NA    NA    NA  0.14  0.62
2  2007-09-23 06:10:00  0.87  0.87  0.05  0.87  0.87  0.05  0.87  0.87  0.05
3  2007-09-23 06:20:00  0.53  0.20  0.52    NA    NA    NA    NA  0.20  0.52
4  2007-09-23 06:30:00  0.03  0.34  0.01    NA    NA    NA    NA  0.34  0.01
5  2007-09-23 06:40:00  0.83  0.92  0.37  0.83  0.92  0.37  0.83  0.92  0.37
6  2007-09-23 06:50:00  0.70  0.94  0.27    NA    NA    NA    NA  0.94  0.27
7  2007-09-23 07:00:00  0.51  0.98  0.49    NA    NA    NA    NA  0.98  0.49
8  2007-09-23 07:10:00  0.65  0.70  0.98    NA    NA    NA    NA  0.70  0.98
9  2007-09-23 07:20:00  0.72  0.05  0.55  0.72  0.05  0.55  0.72  0.05  0.55
10 2007-09-23 07:30:00  0.99  0.16  0.12  0.99  0.16  0.12  0.99  0.16  0.12
# ... with 41,277 more rows
```

(And, to clean up the duplicated columns, simply use `select` once you are done with them.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R solution that should work:

```
is.na(TDF$V1[setdiff(seq_len(nrow(TDF)), match(TDF$Date, TDF2$Date))]) <- TRUE
```

The `match` function returns the observation positions in TDF where the same Date is present in TDF2. `setdiff` turns this output into the complement of this set, that is the set of observations in TDF where the Dates do not match. The values of TDF$V1 are set to NA for these observations using the `is.na<-` method.

Comment: Thanks for the base R solution, too!